# EF Core connection string settings with azure functions and web api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have 2 projects
1.ASP.NET Core WEB API
2. Azure function

Both are hosted on a azure.
I also have different accounts for development and production, hense I need to have different connection strings depending on environment the application are deployed on.

For entity framework I use a separate project which the 2 application refer to.

Whene the separate project is used from weba api I can read a connection string this way

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                            .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))

            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: false)
            .Build();

        var cs = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(cs);
    }
}
```

But there's no appsettings.json file for trigger. What can I do in this case?

Comment: ``But there's no appsettings.json file for trigger`` ? Where do you want to have appsetting.json ?

Comment: @TonyNgo on the server where the trigger is deployed

Comment: Why dont you create 1 ? I personally create appsetting.json when using azure function project

Comment: @TonyNgo I did create, but it works only locally. When I deploy the azure function via Visual studio the appsettings.json is omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Local Development use an `Environment Variable` to store your connection string.
(Right click your `Azure Function Project` in `Visual Studio` select `properties`, `Debug` and you will be able to add an `Environment Variable` there. This will be stored in `launchsettings.json`) 
For example you could call it `MSSQL_CONN_STR`

When Deployed to `Azure` use `Application Settings` 
(Goto `Function app` click `Configuration` and you can add a new Application Setting/Environment variable with the same key as above (`MSSQL_CONN_STR`) but with your `production` value for the connection string)

In your C# code you can get the `Environment Variable` the same as you have above

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSSQL_CONN_STR");
```

From MS regarding Application Settings for Azure Function App

> Application Settings are exposed as environment variables for access by your application at runtime